# Start Meteor server and let other computers access it

Tags: meteor

In Rails or Django, you can allow other devices to access your server by specifying the server address as 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost:3000. How can you do the same in Meteor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the interface and port using the command `meteor --port host:port`

In your case it would be `meteor --port 0.0.0.0:3000`.

Type `meteor --help` to see all tasks. The default task is *run*. `meteor help run` will show all options.